# How to blend/merge two images with pgm format in a c++ program

Tags: c++, image, class, matrix, blend

So I am new to this and also new to c++ but I am stuck in creating this class to blend two input images. I know that I have to create a blank matrix, input the two images to be blended, for each pixel of the empty matrix set it equal to the average of that same pixel location in the other two images, the hard part is writing the code for it....any input is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: If you are doing C++, check out OpenCV. That will do fine for your task.

Answer (score 2):

The PGM format is really simple: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_graymap

So use that info to read the images into arrays, then do just as you said, iterate over the arrays and stick the average pixel values into another array. Then write that out into another file and use an image program that can view pgm images to see your result.

Here's some code that writes out a 3 pixel by 3 pixel pgm image:

```
std::cout << "P2\n";
std::cout << "3 3\n";
std::cout << "10\n";
std::cout << "0 10 0\n";
std::cout << "10 0 10\n";
std::cout << "0 10 0\n";
```

Here's some code that uses valarrays to do the blending:

```
std::valarray<int> imageA,imageB;
//add code to load image data into valarrays here
//the next line does the blending, adding corresponding pixel values together and dividing by two to get the average
std::valarray<int> blend = (imageA + imageB) / 2;
```

Comment: Thank you!! I understand everything you have just stated completely but I don't know where to start with code. Can you give me sample of source code and how to implement this?

Comment: Well, here's some code that writes out a 3 pixel by 3 pixel pgm image:

    std::cout << "P2\n";
    std::cout << "3 3\n";
    std::cout << "10\n";
    std::cout << "0 10 0\n";
    std::cout << "10 0 10\n";
    std::cout << "0 10 0\n";

Answer (score 0):

Well first you'll need to read the image from the disk and into memory.  It's probably best to find a .png library otherwise you'll have to roll your own.  Here's a starting point for that (http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/pngaptk.html).

Next you'll need to take the output from the png reader and convert it to the format you want.  Likely the output will already be a 2D array, so you'll be set there.  Then you just read each file (if they're large, i.e., can't fit in memory) then you'll need to do it by tiles or scanlines, average the arrays, and then send the new array you created back to the png writer API.

If this HAS to be done in c++, that's the general way you can do it.  If you can get hold of IDL or ENVI this could be done in about 5 lines of code.

Comment: for all of this, probably OpenCV is the best

Comment: Thanks! I have the two images that I want to blend but when I download them they automatically convert to pmg from jpeg. I am working in a linux environment can I get IDL or ENVI off of this?

Comment: The question is about `pgm` not `png`

Comment: whoops, sorry about the pgm png confusion - sometimes my brain doesn't parse right.  IDL and ENVI is cros splatform, but not free, so unless you have university or work access, it's probably out of reach.